# Why doesn't Apache CXF write a custom exception to response?

Tags: java, exception, cxf

while implementing a SSL-secured WebService with Apache CXF v2.7.3 I wanted to test how a custom exception class (e.g. MyException) is handled by the client.

Therefore I have the following server-side method:

```java
@WebMethod
public void foo() throws MyException {
    throw new MyException("test!");
}
```

I have also configured to log in- and outgoing messages in the cxf.xml via:

```xml
<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
<jaxws:inInterceptors>
 <ref bean="logInbound"/>
</jaxws:inInterceptors>
<jaxws:outInterceptors>
 <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
</jaxws:outInterceptors>
```

Calling this function with a client results in following console-output

```
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Address: https://localhost:8443/WebApp/services/ClientService
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[184], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], host=[localhost:8443], pragma=[no-cache], SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[Apache CXF 2.7.3]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="http://services.client.test.cloud.org/"/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
18.02.2013 22:49:02 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
INFO: Application {http://services.client.test.cloud.org/}ClientService#{http://services.client.test.cloud.org/}foo has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.cloud.test.client.exception.MyException: test!
18.02.2013 22:49:02 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
INFO: Application {http://services.client.test.cloud.org/}ClientService#{http://services.client.test.cloud.org/}foo has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

The client gets a "Error reading XMLStreamReader." due to a "Unexpected EOF". I guess, that no response is written by the server. Do you know why **2** exceptions are thrown and why there isn't any response to the client?
I already searched for exceptions not redirected to the client in Apache CXF-applications, but could not find any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have got a NullPointerException in your outbound filter. Could you provide it please ?

Comment: I searched earlier for how to gain more information of these Exceptions, but I wasn't successful. How can I get more information. "Unwinding now" only reports the first Exception but no stacktrace.